# GTID ignore error on parallel replication

Tags: mysql, replication, parallelism, gtid, multi-thread

Im getting an error in replication where GTID and parallel replications are enabled. Now I want to skip one transaction.

I didn't find a way to do that.

#### Last_SQL_Error:

```
Worker 48 failed executing transaction '' at master log mysql-bin.002980, end_log_pos 448844064; Error 'Operation DROP USER failed for 'appi'@'10.0.0.10'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'drop user 'appi'@'10.0.0.10''
```

#### GTID Info:

```
  Retrieved_Gtid_Set: c924545b-a3e3-11e8-8a39-42010a280410:1-6798729399


    Executed_Gtid_Set: 26e8b1bf-a4ca-11e8-b64f-42010a280415:1-56,
        c924545b-a3e3-11e8-8a39-42010a280410:1-6789350755:6789350757-6789490840:6789490842-6789490901:6795994381:6796336449-6796336451:6796734964:6796760916:6796785072
```